# Декоратор скрывает self

Tags: python

Я пытаюсь создать декоратор, который похож на `property` для своих задач, но моя реализация, которая подобна `property` на [чистом Python](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#properties) не работает. Я не могу получить доступ к переменным класса до оборачивания через `self`. Вот минимальный воспроизводимый пример:

```
class MyWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, first=None, second=None) -> None:
        self.first = first
        self.second = second

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.first is not None:
            self.first(*args, **kwargs)
        
        if self.second is not None:
            self.second(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def second_handler(self, func):
        wrapper = type(self)(self.first, func)
        return wrapper
        
        
class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
    
    @MyWrapper
    def foo(self):
        print(f'Hello, {self.name}!')
    
    @foo.second_handler
    def foo(self):
        print(f'Bye, {self.name}!')
    
    
def main(*args, **kwargs):
    instance = TestClass('User')
    instance.foo()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Должен вывести:

```
Hi User!
Bye, User!
```

В момент вызова, `self` подменяется декоратором и я теряю связь с атрибутами исходного класса.

Comment: В настоящем property ещё переопределён метод [\_\_get\_\_](https://pythonz.net/references/named/object.__get__/), который, вероятно, и творит магию по запоминанию правильного self

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно реализовать дескриптор — специальный класс, который содержит метод `__get__` (и другие методы, например `__set__`, если нужно переопределить присваивание атрибуту объекта). Такой класс может быть использован как декоратор для методов. Собственно в примере по вашей ссылке `property` и реализован как дескриптор (методы `__get__`, `__set__`, `__delete__`, `__set_name__` - это специфические для дескрипторов методы).

Пришлось немного поколодовать, потому что сходу не вспомнил как это работает, минимальный пример такой:

```
class MyWrapper:
    _second_handler = None
    
    def __init__(self, method):
        self.method = method
    
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        self.obj = obj
        return self
    
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.method(self.obj, *args, **kwargs)
        if self._second_handler is not None:
            self._second_handler(self.obj, *args, **kwargs)
    
    def second_handler(self, method):
        self._second_handler = method
        return self


class TestClass:
    def __init__(self, name) -> None:
        self.name = name
    
    @MyWrapper
    def foo(self):
        print(f'Hello, {self.name}!')
    
    @foo.second_handler
    def foo(self):
        print(f'Bye, {self.name}!')


def main():
    instance = TestClass('User')
    instance.foo()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Тут `__get__` будет вызван при попытке обращения к атрибуту `foo`, в него же в параметр `obj` передастся объект, у которого атрибут запрашивается, его нужно сохранить и использовать как `self` при вызове сохраненных методов.

Comment: Это именно то, что я и хотел, идеально, спасибо!